# Oracle sql not grabbing day for the current date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the day of the week for the asofdate field.  I am receiving an error using Oracle SQL that states:  'a non numeric character was found where a numeric character was expected.'  That error is for this query:

```
select to_char(to_date(max(distinct(asofdate)), 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'DY') from PS_Z_EXS251AE_EMP
```

the below query returns '1/6/2015'

```
select max(distinct(asofdate)) from PS_Z_EXS251AE_EMP
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you by any chance storing dates in `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` columns?`1/6/2015` won't be converted to a date using the mask `mm/dd/yyyy`. P.S. You don't need `DISTINCT` when using `MAX()`

Comment: I tried it works as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49063/2/0
you have some invalid content in asofdate

Comment: it's stored as a date

Comment: Then why are you trying to convert to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `asofdate` is stored as a date/time data type, then why are you converting it to a date.  Also, why are you using `max()`:

```
select to_char(asofdate, 'DY')
```

If `asofdate` is stored as a string, then you should probably fix the data.  Why are you storing a date as a string.  That is the wrong type.

If you want the day of the week of the maximum date, which your question suggests, then just do:

```
select to_char(max(asofdate), 'DY')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
select distinct max(extract(day from asofdate)) from from PS_Z_EXS251AE_EMP;
```

Comment: i need the day of the week though, not the day

Comment: then add modulo 7 + 1 to that query